# Smooth functions for which $f(x)$ is rational if and only if $x$ is rational

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis

A friend of mine introduced me to the following question: Does there exist a smooth function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, ($f \in C^\infty$), such that $f$ maps rationals to rationals and irrationals to irrationals and is nonlinear?

I posed this question earlier in math.stackexchange.com ([link to the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13373/smooth-functions-for-which-fx-is-rational-if-and-only-if-x-is-rational)) where it received considerable interest. There hasn't been an answer so far, but one commenter suggested to bring it here.

**Related results**

- The friend who told me the problem
  has been able to prove that no
  polynomial satisfies the required
  conditions.
- If we required just that $f \in C^1$, then we can cut and paste the function
  $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ to provide a nonlinear example:
  $$f(x) = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{x-1} + 1, & x \le 0 \\\\ \frac{1}{x+1} - 1, & x \ge 0\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There are such functions. Moreover any diffeomorphism $f_0:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ can be approximated by such $f$. For the sake of simplicity I assume that $f_0'\ge 2$ everywhere.

Enumerate the rationals: $\mathbb Q=\{r_1,r_2,\dots\}$, and construct a sequence $f_0,f_1,f_2,\dots$ of self-diffeomorphisms of $\mathbb R$ satisfying the following:

- $f_{2k-1}(r_k)\in\mathbb Q$, and $f_n(r_k)$ is the same for all $n\ge 2k-1$
- $f_{2k}^{-1}(r_k)\in\mathbb Q$, and $f_n^{-1}(r_k)$ is the same for all $n\ge 2k$.
- The first $k$ derivatives of the difference $f_k-f_{k-1}$ are bounded by $2^{-k}$ everywhere on $\mathbb R$.

Such a sequence has a limit $f$ in $C^\infty$, and this limit is a diffeomorphism satisfying $f(\mathbb Q)\subset\mathbb Q$ and $f^{-1}(\mathbb Q)\subset\mathbb Q$.

The sequence $\{f_i\}$ can be constructed by induction. To construct $f_{2k-1}$ from $g:=f_{2k-2}$, consider $g(r_k)$. If it is rational, let $f_{2k-1}=g$. If not, let $I$ be an open interval containing $r_k$ and not containing any of the points $r_i$ and $g^{-1}(r_i)$ for $i\le k-1$. (Note that $r_k$ is different from these points due to the fact that $g(r_k)\notin\mathbb Q$). Then define $f_{2k-1}=g+\varepsilon\cdot h$ where $h$ is your favorite smooth function with support contained in $I$ and such that $h(r_k)\ne 0$,
$\varepsilon$ is so small that the above derivative estimates hold and is chosen so that $f_{2k-1}(r_k)\in\mathbb Q$. To construct $f_{2k}$ from $f_{2k-1}$, do a similar perturbation near the pre-image of $r_k$, assuming it is not yet rational.

Comment: Are there any examples of such functions, which can be computed by an algorithm (efficiently)?

Answer (score 9):

In the answer to this [close question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42460/is-a-real-power-series-that-maps-rationals-to-rationals-defined-by-a-rational-fun/42464#42464) 
I remarked how to make an entire, non polynomial function bijecting two assigned countable dense sets $A$ and $B$.

Also, you can make a non-analytic $C^\infty$ self-diffeo of $\mathbb{R}$ that bijects $A$ and $B$ with similar procedure. Say a $C^\infty$ diffeo, which is not the identity map, but with a tangency of infinite order to the identity map at $0$.

Comment: @Pietro: I don't understand how you can run your procedure described *as is* in that other question here. You say: "inductively add only odd degree polynomials $p_n$, that vanish on the (finitely many) already settled points, and do not destroy the invertibility on $\mathbb{R}$, but if you start with $p_1(x) = qx$ for some rational $q$, then the "already settled points" is already in fact all the points that you want...

Comment: that's no problem, "already settled" just means the first (approximatively) $n/2$ of $A$ plus their images, and the first $n/2$ of $B$ plus their pre-images.

Comment: Ah, so you are implicitly using an enumeration of the two sets. Okay. 

Comment: yes, it was explicit in the lines above. Sorry, I though it was clear enough.

Comment: So, if you fix enumeration for A, how you get enumeration for B? I am trying to construct explicit example.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that given any two dense subsets $A,B\subset(0,1)$, there is an absolutely monotone function $[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ which carries $A$ to $B$.  I don't know the exact proof of this, but the idea is very simple: you enumerate the elements of $A$ and $B$, then take the first element of $A$, and associate it with an appropriate element of $B$, then the first element of $B$ and associate it with an appropriate element of $A$, then associate the second element of $A$ to an appropriate element of $B$, etc.

I am fairly certain that some variation on this should work for your problem.

Comment: The question asks for a *smooth* function

Comment: Also, the problem is not to prove that such functions exist, it's to find out if there are nonlinear examples.