# Maps preserving algebraic numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory

Suppose $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is a map with your favorite smoothness condition (say, $C^1, C^{\infty}$ or holomorphic) and suppose that $f(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})\subset\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. Is $f$ a polynomial? (I.e., if you chose $C^1$ or $C^{\infty}$ in the beginning, then is $f$ a polynomial in $z$ and $\overline{z}$, and if you chose holomorphic, then is $f$ a polynomial in $z$?)

I imagine this is a well-known problem, but I don't remember having seen it before. A holomorphic counter-example would be quite impressive, though I doubt such a thing exists.

Comment: The same sorts of arguments used to answer this question:

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/48910/smooth-functions-for-which-fx-is-rational-if-and-only-if-x-is-rational

also answer yours.  Basically, given dense, countable sets $A,B\subset \mathbb{C}$, there is an entire function which takes $A$ to $B$.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is indeed very well-known. There are plenty of counterexamples. In fact, there's a remarkable construction due to van der Poorten of a "transcendental" entire function $f$ such that $f$ and all its derivatives map any algebraic number $\alpha$ into $\mathbb Q (\alpha)$. See

> A.J. van der Poorten, [Transcendental entire functions mapping every algebraic number field into itself](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=4860012), J. Austral.Math. Soc. **8** (1968), 192–193.

Answer (score 3):

$f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C} \:$ given by $\: f(z) = 0 \:$ shows that $f$ can be a polynomial.

[This answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42460/is-a-real-power-series-that-maps-rationals-to-rationals-defined-by-a-rational-fun/42465#42465) show that $f$ can be holomorphic and not a polynomial.

Unless I'm missing something, that answer works just as well

to show that $f$ can be an [entire function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function) and not a polynomial.