# Nonlinear smooth bijection from $\mathbb Q$ to itself

Tags: real-analysis, rational-functions

Is there a bijection $\phi: \mathbb Q \to \mathbb Q$ such that

- $\phi$ is nonlinear: different from $ax+b$,
- $\phi$ is smooth: the extension $\hat{\phi}$ of $\phi$ over $\mathbb R$ is $\mathcal C^2$ ?

What if we require $\mathcal C^\infty$?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/48910/smooth-functions-for-which-fx-is-rational-if-and-only-if-x-is-rational?rq=1

Comment: $x \mapsto {x^3 \over 1+x^2}$

Comment: @MartinHairer That doesn't look surjective to me (no rational value of $x$ maps to $1$).

Comment: As written, this is a special-case of the question znt links to.

Comment: Sort of, except this question imposes bijectivity. Fortunately, this condition was treated by Pietro Majer in his solution over there.

Comment: @ToddTrimble That's what happens when one types too fast and too late at night...